# Rspec: Access a controller concern's methods in request specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I have a controller concern defined as follows:

```rb
module Auth
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

  def sign_in(user)
    session[:customer_id] = user.id
    self.current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
...
# other methods
end
```

And this module is included in the `ApplicationController`:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include Auth

  helper_method :signed_in?, :current_user, :current_user?
  before_action :authorize
end
```

The questions I have:

- should we really extend `extend ActiveSupport::Concern` in a concern? If so wy and when not?
- how can I enable the concern module so that its methods could be re-used in RSpec request specs?

I tried to add the following in `spec/support/utilities.rb`:

```rb
include ApplicationHelper
include Auth
```

as well as required all the files from `spec/support` directory in `rails_helper.rb` and included the above modules:

```rb
# Require all the files in support directory
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|
...
  # include ApplicationHelper
  config.include ApplicationHelper, type: :feature
  config.include Auth, type: :request
...
end
```

Now, when running a `requests/customers_spec.rb`:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe "/customers", type: :request do
describe "GET /index" do
    it "renders a successful response" do
      customer = create(:customer)
      sign_in(customer)
      get customers_url
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
...
```

it fails with:

```
Failures:

  1) /customers GET /index renders a successful response
     Failure/Error: session[:customer_id] = user.id
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/controllers/concerns/auth.rb:7:in `sign_in'
     # ./spec/requests/customers_spec.rb:10:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What am I missing?
I'm using Rails `6.0.3`, rspec-rails `4.0.1`.

Comment: It seems like at least an initial request should be done to enable session: ```ruby
def session
  @ request.session
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to was to add the following method to the `spec/support/login_macros.rb`:

```rb
module LoginMacros
  def sign_in_with_browser(user)
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'E-mail', with: user.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: user.password
    click_button 'Login'
  end

  def sign_out_with_browser
    click_link 'Logout'
  end
  
# to enable user authentication in request specs
  def login_without_browser(user)
    post login_url, params: { email: user.email, password: 'secret' }
  end
end
```

Then test a protected end-point in the above request spec as follows:

```rb
describe "GET /index" do
    it "renders a successful response" do
      customer = create(:customer)
      
      login_without_browser(customer)
      get customers_url
      expect(response).to be_successful
    end
  end
```